# How to prevent the call of oncreate() and oncreateView() to occur TWICE when fragment is rotated?

Tags: android, rotation, fragment

I am saving the object in  onsaveInstance(), but after fragment rotation, I get the saved object in oncreate(), the method oncreate(Bundle onsaveInstance) is called for the second time and that time onsaveInstance turn to become null. How I could solve the issue or prevent the call of the oncreate() method to occur twice?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it cold help to use setRetainInstance(true) in your fragment's onCreate() callback method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);    
}
```

If set to "true", when orientation changes the fragment instance is not destroyed (only its view hierarchy is destroyed), it passes from onDestroyView() to onDetach() (skipping onDestroy()), when the Activity is being finished. And when the orientation change completes and a new Activity is created, onAttach() is called, onCreate() is skipped, and onCreateView() called. This way the Fragment retains its state.

For a better understanding of the different ways to save and retrieve fragment's states, I recommend you to read this --> [saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-2/](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-2/)
part 1 is about Activities and part 2 about Fragments.

Comment: Thanks.I try it ,but it doesn't help, even in that case oncerate() method calls twice.

Comment: The normal thing to do when using onSaveInstanceState(), is to check if the bundle is not empty, and then restore the data. something like this "public void onCreate(BundleavedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); if (savedInstanceState != null) { // Restore data. if there is one saved state.}}". I don't know why you say onCreate() is called twice. Maybe if you post your code or Log